# Changed cooke domain cant login

Tags: cookie

Hi there I changed cookie domain, which ovs typed in wrong. One article told me to remove it from PHPmyadmin but sitll cant login, I removed cookie sessions and everything

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following steps work :-

1.Open /opt/lampp/htdocs/magentoprojectname/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

2.Find these 3 lines of code & comment them:-

```
 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
```

3. Try logging in

Are you able to login now?

Comment: I appreciate your help Ajay, thank-you very much.

Comment: You're welcome Ben. Did it solve your problem?